# Method to copy html table selection to array

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a chrome browser plugin which works as follows:

- The user selects a numeric table (by clicking-dragging mouse) from any webpage and "uses" the plugin (either by right-clicking, or by some button)
- The plugin uses the numbers from the selection and creates a bar-chart displaying the data.

I have the required code to make a bar-chart, but it needs to be passed a table. I wish to use the user selection as the table but have no idea how it's done. Any help appreciated. Just need a skeleton to start working on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html

It allows you to select rows in the table and then get the selected rows via a method:

rows().data()